# How to Override the property value in the transform file in WIX during Installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am looking for a suggestion How to Override the property value in the transform file in WIX during Installation.

Basically we have a property - for example **USE_WINDOWS_AUTH**

Consider that, Transform file (.mst) has **USE_WINDOWS_AUTH=1**

Now the requirement is, let the property value in transform be whatever, but WIX code should override it to **USE_WINDOWS_AUTH=0** .

Reason for such requirement is, there is an enhancement happened in the product and clients are still using old properties , which is causing us lots of issues.

So the installer should ignore/override the property value of .mst file.

We tried After="CostFinalize",  Before= "InstallInitialize" and etc. NO luck

```
<SetProperty After="CostFinalize" Id="USE_WINDOWS_AUTH" Value="0"/>
```

Another observation is, we are facing issue in silent mode (/quiet), but not interactive mode..
not sure what I am missing..

Any suggestions or advise please..
Please let me know if I can provide you any other information on this.

Thanks In Advance..
Rajkumar.

Comment: Perhaps your MSI already has a Custom Action that set this property ?
Did you tried to set the property in a command line argument that launch your MSI ?

Comment: @Christophe - Firstly thanks for your response.

Yes we tried to set the property value via command line argument. that worked as expected.

But we are not interested in that approach, because practically when clients install in this way there are high chances that mistakes will happen and lots of documentation and etc need to maintain and mostly on top of that.. we cannot track the installation steps whether they followed properly as part of documentation and difficult for us to spot what is the issue after some years.. :)

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation seems to be below logic is helping me to serve the requirement. Hence Posting here.. which may help someone looking for some clues to the similar requirement.

```
<CustomAction Id='ModifyWindowsAuthValue' Property='USE_WINDOWS_AUTH' Value='0' Execute='immediate' />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action='ModifyWindowsAuthValue' Before="CostFinalize"/>
   //existing other actions
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```